# Django: Create model object with increased version number

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have Model, e.g.:

```
class Example(models.Model):
   title = models.SlugField()
   version = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
   content = models.TextField(blank=True)

   class Meta:
       unique_together = (
           ('title', 'version'),
       )
```

I would like to achieve something like that below but somehow avoid race conditions and make this atomic:

```
e = Example(title='test')
e.version = Example.objects.filter(title=e.title).aggregate(Max('version'))['version__max']+1
e.save()
```

PS. I'm using Django 1.8

Comment: you can't filter before it have saved

Comment: I would add a `BooleanField` to store if this document has the highest version

Comment: From where are your instances saved? Since you have mentioned atomic transactions I assume there is a reason that you can't decorate that function with `@transaction.atomic`. To be sure to understand it, you expect possible race conditions caused by simultaneous requests getting the identical `version__max` and thus one `save()` resulting in an integrity error because of the unique constraint?

Comment: I'm afraid about time between calculation `version` as max possible version `+ 1` and calling `save()` method. Can I wrap 2nd and 3rd line in `with transaction.atomic():` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm overriding `.save()` like so:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    title = models.SlugField()
    version = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ('title', 'version'),
        )
    
    def _highest_version(self):
        return Example.objects.filter(title=self.title).aggregate(Max('version'))['version__max'] or 0
    
    def save(self):
        if self.version is None:
            self.version = self._highest_version() + 1
        return super().save()
```

(Adjust as necessary for your validation story)

Comment: your solution is not atomic

Comment: Indeed it is not! I'm not certain if transactions would guarantee this, if you need to reach for more advanded SQL features, or if you'd have to hack the ORM to allow expressions in the `INSERT`.

In my case, I'm only creating snapshots at specific process points in a low-traffic app. I consider the likelihood of a conflict low, and if it does happen, the `unique_together` will prevent it from entering the database.

Comment: I had suggested to use `transaction.atomic()` (imported from `django.db`) to fix this issue and to make this solution atomic. May I know why you removed my edit [Zoe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6296561/zoe)? Thank you